# SDWebImage doesn't show locally stored image on a real device but it shows up in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I'm using SDWebImages library to get image for thumbnails. It is working seemlesly.

However when I navigate from video to a controller where I play video, I need to show thumbnail once again. I need an image path to pass to the player.

The problem is if I pass the same URL the player will download the image once again. In order to avoid this behaviour i'm trying to get the image from disc which is already stored there by sdwebimages library.

```
/// get thumbnail from cache
var thumbnail: String?
if (video?.hasThumbnail) {
   let urlString = "https://test.com/image/001.png"
   if let path = SDImageCache.shared.cachePath(forKey: urlString) {
       thumbnail = path
   } else {
       thumbnail = urlString
   }
}
```

This is working on a simulator, but NOT on the real device.

Answer (score 0):

Please read more about [how to use](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage#how-to-use)

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Comment: In my first sentence I say I use the library to get the thumbnails, and it works with no issues. My files are then stored in the cache and on disc. The above code is getting the path of the locally stored image. It is able to pull the image on simulator but not on the real device.